# MIPS Pipelining logic to solve data hazards

Tags: assembly, mips, forwarding

The code below runs on a 5-stage pipelined datapath. I am having a hard time knowing whether my understanding of how pipelining works is correct or not. In my attempt below, I try to solve a data hazard in a datapath with no data forwarding unit, by inserting 'bubbles' in the oppropriate places. My first question is, is my pipelining logic below correct?

My second question is assuming there IS a forwarding unit in the datapath, from MEM->EX and from WB->EX, how would that change my logic from the first question?

```
add t0, s1, s2
add t1, t0, s3
sub t2, t0, t1
xor t3, t2, a0
lw t4, 0(t7)
slt t5, t4, t3
```

This is my attempt for question 1:

```
add t0, s1, s2 //IF add1 instruction
nop            //ID add1 instruction
nop            //EX add1 instruction
add t1, t0, s1  //MEM add1 instruction,  IF add2 instruction
nop             //WB add1 instruction,  ID add2 instruction
nop            //EX add2 instruction
nop            //MEM add2 instruction
nop            //WB add2 instruction
sub t2, t0, t1 //IF sub instruction
nop            //ID sub instruction
nop            //EX sub instruction
nop            //MEM sub instruction
xor t3, t2, a0 //WB sub instruction, IF xor instruction
lw t4, 0(t7)   //ID xor instruction, IF lw instruction
nop            //EX xor instruction, ID lw instruction 
nop            //MEM xor instruction, EX lw instruction 
nop            //WB xor instruction, MEM lw instruction
slt t5, t4, t3 //WB lw instruction, IF slt instruction
```

Comment: Is this CS 251 from University of Waterloo by chance?

Comment: It would help if you could post some images of the circuitry, because there are different data-forwarding setups. Also you can stagger your instructions on pipelines to see where the hazards are without and without dataforwarding

Comment: images are not given and are not neccessary to solve this problem. thanks anyways though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at the pipeline diagrams illustrated here: https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs251/S12/a4.pdf and map your instructions to similarly staggered pipelines, and it will help you visualize the data hazards.

In addition, the exact data-forwarding implementation will depend on the design of the questions on your assignments, which will affect how many nops you need.